# Reagents and intermediates for synthetic route

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: Conversion of cyclohexene to... Loong please help me]

What are reagents 1 and 2, and what compound is A?

I was trying to solve this problem, and some ideas popped up (reductive ozonolysis, then aldol condensation and ionic addition, maybe?) but I wanted to be certain.

Thanks a lot in advance! Sorry for possible bad english.

Comment: The direct product of the aldol addition is the beta-hydroxyketone shown there. As long as you don't eliminate H2O, then you'll be fine